# How to call out probability values for each class using python in decision trees

Tags: python

How can i call out the probability of each class value from the prediction model.

Python code :

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini',
    splitter='best',
    max_depth=None,
    min_samples_split=2,
    min_samples_leaf=1,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    max_features=None,
    random_state=123,
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    min_impurity_split=None,
    class_weight=None,
    presort=False)

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

# View the dataset with predicted value
   dtree_gini =pd.DataFrame({'Actual':y_test, 'Predicted':y_pred})
   dtree_gini1 = pd.merge(X_test, dtree_gini, left_index=True,right_index=True);
   dtree_gini1.head(5)

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfZz.png)

[desire outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6wQs.png)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba) like so:

```
y_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```